# Problem of pulling the image with the TypeScript of an external Api

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Speak dev! I have a problem when importing images from an external api, I tag it: <img src = {photos [0] .src} /> However it doesn't recognize from .src, can someone explain to me how this works?

Note: It will pull everything at once, because I just wanted to do a test to see if I would be able to pull the api.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Post {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  preco: string;
  fotos: string;
  descricao: string;
  src: string;


}

const Dasboard: React.FC = () => {

  const [dados, setDados] = useState<Post [] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://ranekapi.origamid.dev/json/api/produto/');
      const data = await response.json();
      setDados(data);
      console.log(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
       <div>
       {dados && dados.map(({id, nome, preco, fotos, descricao}) => (

    <li key={id}>
      {nome}
      {preco}
      <img src={fotos[0].src} alt={fotos[0].titulo}></img>
      {descricao}
   </li>
))}

        </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default Dasboard;
```

Comment: In `Post` type definitions `fotos` is a `string`, not and array of strings, but in `Dashboard` you use it as an array, that's the problem.
Also would be nice if you translated variables in your code to english before posting, because it would make it easier to keep track of variables and spot the error

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I managed to solve the error, it was in the interface, the photos were inside an array, so I needed to break down this array: photos: [{src: string, title: string}];
But thanks for the tip, I will do this in the next questions!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the discussion from the comments, @AlexChashin is correct in pointing out that you defined `fotos` as a `string` and you need to be defining it as an array of objects.

When you but brackets around the object like in your comment `photos: [{src: string, title: string}]` you are making a [Tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) which means that it as an array with exactly one entry which is that object.  This is fine if that's what the API returns.  However if the API might have 0 photos, or if you want to be able to access images other than just the first, you want to define it as an [Array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) which can have any length by adding the brackets at the end `photos: {src: string, title: string}[]`.

If there is a possibility of an empty array, you may also want to check that `fotos[0]` exists before the `img` tag.

(also I think you need `{!!dados && dados.map` instead of `{dados && dados.map` so that it evaluates it as a `boolean`).